# Were Kyber crystals mentioned in the Star Wars movies prior to Rogue One?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, kyber-crystal

In [*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_One) there are various mentions of [Kyber crystals](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kyber_crystal) - relating to lightsabers, the [Death Star](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Superlaser), and the [Jedha temple](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedha_City).

From what I can recall - this didn't come up before.

[Lightsabers](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lightsaber) were just constructed as part of the [rite of passage](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Knighting_ceremony) of Jedi and [some crystal](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lightsaber_crystal) was involved. I don't recall there being a connection to the Death Star.

To me it feels a lot like [energon cubes](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Energon_cube) from the [*Transformers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Transformers_(TV_series)) TV series (the 1984 cartoon).

**Were Kyber crystals mentioned in the *Star Wars* movies prior to *Rogue One*?**

Comment: They were first called such in the Clone Wars series. The necessity of crystals for lightsabers, though, is an older idea, as your link shows. They were not called kyber, but...potatoes, potahtos.

Comment: @Adamant nasty "taters". In regards to the crystal question though, I've come to understand it as the difference between saying I need batteries for my light saber or I need Lithium-Ion batteries for my light saber. We knew that the light sabers needed crystals and maybe that was enough information to get by "in-universe". Out of universe it seems like small scale retcon.

Comment: Well, those Khyber crystals are indeed more than meets the eye.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No**, they have not been mentioned in the *Star Wars* movies before. They were introduced in Legends material, then discussed in *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* and *Star Wars Rebels*.

[Kyber Crystal: Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kyber_crystal)

Answer (score 5):

They were mentioned as early as 1978's *Splinter of the Minds Eye* by Alan Dean Foster. A Legends character, Halla, wants Luke and Leia to help her find it in a temple on Minban (which was a planet they used in *Solo: A Star Wars Story* as well).

> Halla looked around the table with seriocomic intensity before turning back to them, 'I don't suppose either of you children have ever heard of the Kaiburr crystal? Only a few people familiar with the exploration of Mimban have heard of it. Circarpousian xenoarcheolgists first heard about it on their one and only exploration expedition to this planet.'
>
> <sub>*Splinter of The Minds Eye* - Page 67</sub>

Later she opens a box that contains a piece and has Luke touch it (she also dismisses Leia from touching this where in 1978 she was only known to be a regal princess (although tough) with no Force sensitivity). Luke senses it magnifies the Force. I do not know if it is meant to construct lightsabers in this novel yet but it could. Have not gotten that far yet.

Comment: The question was rather looking for movies, but that's a nice catch. If they're explicitly mentioned by name, could you [edit] in a relevant quote? :)